# Same button for close and open dialog jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i have one button but this only open the dialog

I wanted to open and close it with the same button

HTML   `<li><a class="plusnotes" ></a></li>`
JQUERY

```
$(".plusnotes").click(function(){
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
})
```

Thank Guys

Comment: Which dialog library are you using? Also, is the dialog overlay preventing access to the `.plusnotes` element?

Comment: Given the syntax, I made the assumption this was the dialog from jqueryUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the dialog is open to determine if you should close or open it.

```
$(".plusnotes").click(function(){
    if (( "#dialog" ).dialog( "isOpen" )){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
    }else{
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
});
```

Comment: @AntoninoSole  Do you have any errors in the devtools console? Try adding a couple of console.log statements into the if structure of the above answer, so that when you click the button you can check the devtools console and see that the correct console.log was activated.